# using TensorFlow to find optimum of input parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, machine-learning, mathematical-optimization

I'm currently working on a mathematical optimization in architecture.

I created and trained a model in `TensorFlow` (TF).

Now, I want to find the optimum of the input parameters, for example, I want to maximize the incoming sunlight radiation through the window.

I used to find the optimum with `Genetic Algorithm` (GA) to minimize or maximize the fitness function.

Is there a way to find maximum or minimum based on the criteria of input parameters in TF? or should I use the TF model as a fitness function in conjunction with GA?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of these optimizers that Tensorflow has implemented, refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train).

Also, any of your optimizer (like a Genetic Algorithm) can also be modelled using Tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually checked that and i already used the gradient descent optimizer to train the model. The model's prediction is accurate. How can i use the same optimizer in other to find the minimum?

Comment: I do not get what you mean by "use the same optimizer in other"

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase that. the optimizers meant to train the model. is that correct? The test data consist of inputs that each has a specific numeric domain. I want to find the optimum number in each domain based on the model's prediction. and I want the model's prediction to get to the most possible maximum number. would you mind sharing your ideas with me? and is it possible to use the tf. train optimizers for this reason?